# How to do Typescript compile time check to make sure 2 Enums has the same values

Tags: typescript, validation, enums, compilation

I need to have 2 enums with the same Keys but different values. I want to know in compile-time both have the same keys and nothing is missing or added. This is for constants I want to use.

I know I can achieve it by using Interface and create Object for both when the type is the interface I created, but this will prevent me to use `const enum` or just `enum` which has its own benefits.

For example, I want to make sure the following Enums have the same keys:

```
enum Enum1 {
    bar = "bar1",
    baz = "baz1",
}

enum Enum2 {
    bar = "bar2",
    baz = "baz2"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did some search and found quite a simple way to get it, with a small amount of code and with Enums of course.

All the validation check are types which will be gone in final code.

The `// @ts-ignore` it because I am not using the `T` Generic and just need it to validate it `extends never` which we will get when we `Omit` the fields of one Enum from the other and nothing is left, but when any additional field does left the value is not `never` so the compiler will show us error. We will do so for both enums to the other enum.

See the code [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAouEEYoG8BQUNQEYEMBOUAvFAES54IkA06muAXkaQ5TQL6qqiSzwBMKWhnJMy+PtSHYcjYmPoTUHVAHoVUAAIAXAM4BaAJYBzEAHs8wVFoCeAB2C8dYC3EgwAjmBwAbADwAVKGAADy1QABMdKBBgADdgPAA+Ji08MGAAbk4beygAeQBpJGI4Jxd4Dy8-AGtga1MAM3yIAy1fHOBG3kgEKiha+qaOrtcIPkTErI78goESkDLgUcqfXwGuvJa24abRvj71obtO3fgECaygA) in the playground.

```
enum Enum1 {
    bar = "bar1",
    baz = "baz1",
}

enum Enum2 {
    bar = "bar2",
    baz = "baz2"
}

// @ts-ignore
type EnsureEnumEqual<T extends never> = true;

type OK1 = EnsureEnumEqual<keyof Omit<typeof Enum1, keyof typeof Enum2>>;
type OK2 = EnsureEnumEqual<keyof Omit<typeof Enum2, keyof typeof Enum1>>;
```